# Running Python Click Command as Root

Tags: python, command-line, root, sudo, python-click

I am trying to run my a command (generated from Python's click package - https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) with `ROOT` privileges (through the sudo command)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSQPi.png)

I can't seem to find a way to do it, can anyone provide some guidance? Much thanks

Comment: you tried "sudo -E" ?

Comment: Please type the code in the body of the message, instead inserting an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I have found the solution to this problem.

Instead of using `pip3 install .` which will install all the packages and the command into my current user, I have used `sudo pip3 install .`, this will allow me to install the packages and command into my root user account, and hence allow me to then run the command as root, like this, `sudo mycommand argument1 argument2`